# Are there any Chinatowns in New Zealand?

Tags: new-zealand, auckland, wellington

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinatowns_in_Oceania#New_Zealand) says:

> Chinatowns existed on Greys Avenue in Auckland and Haining Street in Wellington up until the 1970s, and there is a growing community in both Christchurch and Dunedin.

Does it mean that nowadays there are no Chinatowns in Auckland and Wellington? The information about Christchurch and Dunedin is vague too. I can't see any places marked as "Chinatown" in NZ on Google Maps.

Comment: If it’s Chinese cuisine or ingredients you are after, there are plenty of Chinese shops in all major towns in NZ - we buy our Chinese food from them rather than the supermarkets.

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  How do you define a Chinatown?  What aspect are you looking for, is it something in particular?  There are huge Asian and Chinese communities in the large NZ cities such as Auckland.  Or are you after an area actually called "Chinatown"?

Comment: @Midavalo I define a Chinatown as an area in a city where there are many Chinese shops and restaurants, and which is a social center for the Chinese community in the city. A city may have a huge Chinese population but the population may be spread out across the city, or alternatively there may be a specific area where the Chinese community is concentrated. The question is whether such specific areas exist in NZ cities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda.

There are for example, historic 'Chinatown' settlements in some old gold mining towns, like [Arrowtown](https://www.doc.govt.nz/parks-and-recreation/places-to-go/otago/places/arrowtown-area/things-to-do/arrowtown-chinese-settlement/).

As for a modern 'Chinatown', in my city - Christchurch, for example, there's a block in an area called Church Corner, that has a bunch of Chinese markets, restaurants and shops:

[image]

However, there are also random Korean and Filipino ones in there too.  Some suburbs have a higher percentage of Chinese compared to others, but not so much a total area you'd call a 'Chinatown'.

(some seriously good food there though, in the are in the map)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.skyscanner.co.nz/news/best-chinatowns-australia-and-new-zealand) lists the Chinatowns in New Zealand and Australia. There is one in Auckland but it quite small in comparison, only 7000m². I also couldn’t find any Chinatowns in any other places than mentioned above, so I think here’s a full list of Chinatowns in NZ:

- Auckland

And I think that’s about it.

Comment: That's a pretty superficial article.  For example, in Sydney alone, in addition to "the" Chinatown, Hurstville, Chatswood and Burwood are solidly Chinese enclaves.